# Lenovo N100 and Samsung SSD 830, shouldn't this go faster than 100MB/s?

Tags: ssd, sata, speed

I recently upgrated my Lenovo N100 0768 with a Samsung SSD 830 - specified to support 520 MB/s read and 320MB/s write. However, having only SATA1 with max. of 150MB/s speed, it has to run in a slower mode - of course.

But, shouldn't it be more on the edge of this limit than ranging between 90-115MB/s and averaging around 103MB/s? Or is this really as much as I can expect? Tested with HD-Tach.

Has anyone comparable results on a SATA1 controller with a SSD drive faster than SATA1? Preferably similar to the Samsung 830?

Comment: Just sounds like overhead to me - that's poor performance, but you'll never read the theoretical max so...  (Anyway it's still better than a rotational drive, right?)

Comment: I agree, overhead can take a big bite, but you should be seeing another 20Mb/s or so. Have you updated the firmware on the drive?

Comment: @Shinrai - it's way better than my rotational, and I don't expect the theoretical mam, but on an otherwise idle win7 system with 3GB and intel T5600 Core2Duo, I would expect an average around 120-130MBs/s - just like James suggested.

Comment: not, jet, quite freshly bought though. I will try this *AS SSD* tool and google, if there is anything left, which I should update/change/configure

Comment: Yeah, I would naively expect a bit higher than that as well myself, so no disagreement.